# Knockout show/hide not working with durandal

Tags: knockout.js, durandal

I have used knockout `if` binding to show/hide a div based on value from model.

```
var model = {
        // Model-----------------------------------------------
        router: router,
        chosen: chosen,
        selectedItems: [],
        selectedItemsList: [],
        p: {
            Id: null,
            IsValid : false
        },

         activate: function (id) {
            var self = this;
            var apiRoute = 'test/id';
            return api.GetModel(apiRoute, null, self);
         },
         approve: function ()
         {
            return self.activate(1);
         }
 };

 <!-- ko if: p.IsValid -->
    <div></div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

This works when the application is loaded first time. But to refresh the view I am calling `self.activate()` in a button click.  After calling `self.activate()`, the show/hide functionality stops working.

Can someone help me identify what is the issue?

Comment: You need to share more code.

Comment: var model = {
        // Model-----------------------------------------------
        router: router,
        chosen: chosen,
        selectedItems: [],
        selectedItemsList: [],
        p: {
            Id: null,
            IsValid : false
        },
  
   activate: function (id) {
      var self = this;
   var apiRoute = 'test/id';
   return api.GetModel(apiRoute, null, self);
   },
   approve: function ()
   {
   return self.activate(1);
   }
 };
 
 <!-- ko if: p.IsValid -->
    <div></div>
<!-- /ko -->

Comment: You have an edit link at the bottom left of your question

Comment: Hmmm.. You don't seem to use observables here

Comment: For what reason would you need to reactivate the view to refresh it?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [the "visible" binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html)

in the viewModel

```
   viewModel ={
     activate: activate,
     title: 'Bewertung',
     attached: attached,
     someVal : ko.observable(true)
   }


  return viewModel
```

in the view

```
 <div data-bind="visible: someVal"></div>
```

to change the visibility you can access `"someVal"`like this `viewModel.someVal(false)` from `attached` for example

Comment: Thanks for the response, but visible also didn't work

Comment: var model = {
        // Model-----------------------------------------------
        router: router,
        chosen: chosen,
        selectedItems: [],
        selectedItemsList: [],
        p: {
            Id: null,
            IsValid : false
        },
  
   activate: function (id) {
      var self = this;
   var apiRoute = 'test/id';
   return api.GetModel(apiRoute, null, self);
   },
   approve: function ()
   {
   return self.activate(1);
   }
 };
 
 <!-- ko if: p.IsValid -->
    <div></div>
<!-- /ko -->

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
viewModel ={
 activate: activate,
 title: 'Bewertung',
 attached: attached,
 someVal : ko.observable(true)
```

}

```
<div data-bind="visible: someVal()"></div>
```